# jQuery Progress bar value = variable

Tags: jquery

I want to make a jQuery progress bar where the value is that of an variable.

```
var mynumber = [whatever value]
$(function () {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: mynumber
    });
});
```

I have searched on the net but can't find this anywhere.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you didn't find [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/)?

Answer (score 1):

As `value` can be of the type `boolean` or `number` (according to the [jQuery API](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#option-value)), you have to parse your variable into the specific type first:

```
var mynumber = [whatever value]
$(function () {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: parseInt(mynumber, 10)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", mynumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to link JQueryUI and JQuery, look at this code:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/9GVPq/1)

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var number=37;
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: number
});
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
}
```